# What are pros and cons of different edge detection algorithms

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, fuzzy-logic, sobel, canny-operator

Can someone describe different edge detection algorithm to detect edges in  an image with pros and cons of their uses. 
Some of the main algorithms that i was interested in were:
Sobel
FuzzyLogic
Canny

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

From application point of view:

Sobel: Quick but fails to detect weak edges, deals good in presence of noise

FuzzyLogic: Comparatively slow. Require tuning in presence of noise (not sure how much tedious)

Canny: Considered good so far due to non-maximal suppression and two thresholding which extracts most of the edges. Fails badly in presence of noise, need manual tuning of parameters.

Search: Edge detection in Google scholar and you'll get much detailed comparison.

Cheers